# Configuring lsp-mode to run elm-language-server

Tags: lsp-mode

I'm trying to run `lsp-mode` for elm development and according to [lsp-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) elm is supported. Also according to that link, I should only have to clone the [elm-language-server](https://github.com/elm-tooling/elm-language-server) repository, run `npm install` and then `tsc`, all of which I did, without any errors.

After configuring emacs with the following [from here](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode)

```
(require 'lsp-mode)
(add-hook 'elm-mode-hook #'lsp)
(setq lsp-elm-server-install-dir "~/Projects/elm-language-server")
```

everything should be set to go.

When I do this, everything seems to work. `lsp-mode` starts when I open an elm file and it starts the `elm-language-server`. I end up with an `*lsp-log*` buffer, an `*elm-ls*` buffer and an `*elm-ls::stderr*` buffer.

The output from the `*lsp-log*` buffer doesn't look *too* suspicious:

```
Command "node /home/chris/Projects/elm-language-server/out/index.js --stdio" is present on the path.
Found the following clients for /home/chris/Projects/select-elm/src/Main.elm: (server-id elm-ls, priority -1)
The following clients were selected based on priority: (server-id elm-ls, priority -1)
Rebuilding tree-sitter for local Electron version
Fetching tree-sitter
Downloading from https://github.com/tree-sitter/node-tree-sitter/releases/download/v0.14.0/tree-sitter-v0.14.0-node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz
Fetching tree-sitter-elm
Downloading from https://github.com/razzeee/tree-sitter-elm/releases/download/v2.2.4/tree-sitter-elm-v2.2.4-node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz
Rebuild succeeded!
initializing - folder: "file:///home/chris/Projects/select-elm/"
Reading elm.json from /home/chris/Projects/select-elm/elm.json
2 source-dirs found
Found 39 files to add to the project
Adding /home/chris/Projects/select-elm/src/01-button.elm
Received new elm-analyse report with 1 messages
Received new elm-analyse report with 1 messages
Adding /home/chris/Projects/select-elm/src/form.elm
Adding /home/chris/Projects/select-elm/src/Main.elm
Adding /home/chris/Projects/select-elm/src/select.elm
Adding /home/chris/Projects/select-elm/src/text.elm
....
```

although the "-1" in `(server-id elm-ls, priority -1)` might be an indicator something *is* wrong.

The `*elm-ls*` buffer is empty and the `*elm-ls::stderr*` is where there is a definite problem:

```
(node:30435) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: "file" argument must be a non-empty string
(node:30435) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:30435) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file:///home/chris/Projects/select-elm/src/Main.elm'
(node:30435) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5): TypeError: "file" argument must be a non-empty string
(node:30435) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file:///home/chris/Projects/select-elm/src/Main.elm'
(node:30435) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 8): TypeError: "file" argument must be a non-empty string
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything on the web about this. In my elm buffer I simply get an error message on the very first line "Error parsing file". The file does compile using `elm make` though.

Anyone have any idea how to debug this? I'm using elm 0.19.0 and unfortunately the normal [elm-mode](https://github.com/jcollard/elm-mode) isn't an option for me because elm 0.19.0 has created a lot of breaking changes that the maintainers of elm-mode are having a hard time fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Error parsing file is from `elm-analyse` and it has to do with the file not starting with 
module MyModule exposing (..) 
which seems to wreck `elm-analyse` and then the server itself. I only know this because I also had this problem. More info and original discussion can be found here: https://github.com/jcollard/elm-mode/issues/142

Comment: Did you happen to get flycheck type checking to work? I've got lsp-mode using lsp-ui, which uses flycheck and everything else looks really good, but I have to compile the buffer to see when I use a wrong type somewhere.

Comment: I just saw this and checked it out. I just wanted to test something small, and I can see a type mismatch if I do text 1, which is supposed to take a string. However, if I had any other error in the buffer before that one, it doesn't seem to see it. After doing some more testing around it seems like maybe elm-analyse/elm make are getting a version of the buffer that is several edits old.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Still not working. I'll have to look into things some more. So close yet so far away! :)